# Statechart using html/javascript/jquery (dracula graph)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, statechart

I need to draw a state chart ( or as of figure) in my mvc web app. I am using draculajs (http://www.graphdracula.net/).

I need to put two way arrow as shown in the figure but currently the arrows are overlapping.

My code to draw edge:

```
g.addEdge('A', 'B', { label: "son", directed: true });

g.addEdge('B', 'A', { label: "father", directed: true });
```

Can someone help ?

[image]

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: I hope, now my question is appropriate.